# Excel VBA ComboBox1_DropButtonClick Event

Tags: vba, excel

I got macro below which fires twice (showing same MessageBox twice). First when ComboBox1 opens and second when ComboBox1 closes.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
If Me.ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
   MsgBox "Fill text box"
Else
'Do stuff
End If
End Sub
```

Is there any way to make it show MessageBox once.  I want user to select the value in ComboBox1 first before clicking on ComboBox2 DropButton.

Comment: Can you use ComboBox1_Change() instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using the combobox_enter event, but this only checks when the focus is switched

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        ComboBox2.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenNever
    Else
        ComboBox2.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenAlways
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Enter()
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Must first set value to combobox1"
        ComboBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "None", 0
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Select Me", 1
    ComboBox2.AddItem "None", 0
    ComboBox2.AddItem "Select Me", 1

    ComboBox2.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenNever
End Sub
```

My code does some extra things that I just think look pretty, you really only need the _Enter function

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very unelegant work-around using a "count" variable that prompts the MsgBox only the first and not the second time.

```
Dim count As Integer
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
count = count + 1
If Me.ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
   If count = 1 Then
       MsgBox "Fill text box"
   Else
        count = 0
   End If
Else
'Do stuff
End If
End Sub
```

However, I highly suggest to use the `ComboBox1_Change()` event if it's not necessary to use the drop button one.

P.S.: the declaration of the "count" variable needs to stay out of the method. This is due to the fact that:

- if it stays inside, it's a local variable of the method and so loses its modifications every time the method is ended;
- if it stays outside, it will keep the modifications even once the method has ended its run.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matteo.  This is what I was looking for.  I needed to use DropButtonClik event as I wanted to notify user straight after he clicks on the button, where Change and Enter event don't do this.

Comment: No worries @KamranRasheed. If this answer satisfies you, please do not forget to mark it as such;)